# Rails with Postgres - Database roles specific actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, roles

In my Dockerized Rails 5 app with Ruby 2.3 that uses Postgres, I want to run `rake db:create` with a role that has `createdb` permission.

But for my application to run or to run migrations, I don't want to provide the `createdb` permission to the DB role.  Is there a way to use separate users to run `rake db:create` and `rake db:migrate`/application CRUD?

e.g.

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: app_development
  pool: 5
  username: app_name # Currently this role has all permissions
  password: pwd
```

In the above configuration, I want to split it so that the role user `app_name` which has all permissions is not used while the app runs.

Please comment in case of any questions.

Comment: Can you describe your use case for this? If you use an official Docker image to run the database, you can create the database automatically using environment variables, and don't need to run `db:create`. And for a production environment, you would create the database manually anyway.

Comment: I create a separate user, typically in my PG container, that has correct permissions and use that to run migrations.

Comment: My use case is to have separate roles in DB that can create DB/Tables and that can do READ/WRITE operations for Data.  Basically separate DDL from DML.  But seems Rails uses the same user to create the DB and then write/read data from it.